# How to create a dictionary with values representing the amount of times a word is repeated in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
x = ["hi", "hi", "bye", "see", "you", "later"]  
for i in x:  
    sum = x.count(i)    
    y = dict((i, sum) for i in x)  
print(y)
```

When I print this code it gives me a dictionary with key values of 1. However, what I am trying to achieve is for the values in the dictionary to be the number of times each word in the list is repeated. So, for this example: {'hi':2, 'bye':1, 'see':1, 'you':1, 'later':1} is what I am trying to achieve for my output given the input x. Can anyone help me? Thanks :)

Comment: [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Answer (score 1):

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is suitable for this kind of task.

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = ["hi", "hi", "bye", "see", "you", "later"]  

y = defaultdict(int)
for key in x:
    y[key] += 1
print(y)
print(dict(y))
```

---

Add Counter ver. as in comments (much easier than defaultdict).

```
from collections import Counter
x = ["hi", "hi", "bye", "see", "you", "later"]  
y = Counter(x)
print(y)
```

---

Add without importing modules.

```
x = ["hi", "hi", "bye", "see", "you", "later"]  

y = dict()
for key in x:
    if not key in y:
        # y.update({key: 1})
        y[key] = 1
    else:
        y[key] += 1

print(y)
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without importing any modules?

Answer (score 1):

you can have something like this

```
x = ["hi", "hi", "bye", "see", "you", "later"]  
y = {i:x.count(i) for i in x}
print(y)
```

and the results will be

```
{'bye': 1, 'hi': 2, 'later': 1, 'see': 1, 'you': 1}
```